# How to print a line with no field separator in awk?

Tags: regex, list, sorting, awk

I have data like this (file is called `list-in.dat`)

```
a ; b ; c ; i
d
e ; f ; a ; b
g ; h ; i
```

and I want a list like this (output file `list-out.dat`) with all items, in alphabetically order (case insensitive) and each unique item only once.

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
```

My attempt is:

```
awk -F " ; " ' BEGIN { OFS="\n" ; } {for(i=0; i<=NF; i++) print $i} ' file-in.dat | uniq | sort -uf > file-out.dat
```

But I end up with all antries *except* those lines which has only *one* item:

```
a
b
c
e
f
g
h
i
```

> How can I get all (unique, sorted) items no matter how many items are in one line / if the field separator is missing?

Comment: So you want to output all fields alphabetically sorted?

Comment: yes, all unique fields

Comment: wrt `for(i=0;` - field numbers (and array indices and string character positions) start at `1` in awk, not `0`. Your loop would print `$0` (the whole input line) and THEN each of the fields `$1` through `$NF`. wrt `uniq | sort -u` - uniq needs sorted input and sort -u does what uniq does as well as sorting so `uniq | sort -u` doesn't make sense. More importantly, though, there is nothing in your script that would remove a field from a single line and that script would absolutely **not** produce the output you say it does. Post the real script you're having trouble with so we can help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `gnu-awk`:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*;[[:blank:]]*' '{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) uniq[$i]
}
END {
   PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
      for (i in uniq)
         print i
}' file
```

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
```

---

For `non-gnu awk` use:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*;[[:blank:]]*' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) uniq[$i]} 
END{for (i in uniq) print i}' file | sort
```

Comment: Taking the (non-gnu) answer as "correct" since it is the fastest solution (at least on my system).

Comment: Looks like filling `uniq[]` first rather than just printing every field is faster for some distributions of data anyway. I just created a file using `awk 'BEGIN{for (i=1; i<=100000; i++) for (j=1; j<=10; j++) printf "%s%s", i+j, (j<10?OFS:ORS)}' > file` and then running `time awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) unq[$i]} END{for (i in unq) print i}' file | sort > /dev/null` took `real    0m0.475s
user    0m0.389s
sys     0m0.091s` while running `time awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}' file | sort -u > /dev/null` took `real    0m2.321s
user    0m2.343s
sys     0m0.030s`. You live and learn...

Comment: Thanks so much for benchmarking Ed. I guess this is what OP has also stated in comments above.

Comment: The above file had a lot of duplicated values. For a file with no duplicate values as created by `awk 'BEGIN{for (i=1; i<=1000000; i+=10) for (j=1; j<=10; j++) printf "%s%s", i+j, (j<10?OFS:ORS)}' > file` the timing for both approaches was almost identical around `real    0m3.196s
user    0m3.139s
sys     0m0.170s`. So populating `uniq[]` first and looping on it seems to be the better approach for execution speed as it's never any slower and sometimes much faster. Not what I expected at all!

Comment: @EdMorton, Thanks a TON Ed sir and anubhava sir for this nice conversation wI learnt too from this one, thank you and stay safe both of you GEMs :)

Comment: @EdMorton: And both `awk` versions are **way** faster than a `sed` that replaces delimiters with `\n` piped to `sort -u` btw

Answer (score 4):

```
awk -F' ; ' -v OFS='\n' '{$1=$1} 1' ip.txt | sort -fu
```

- `-F' ; '` sets space followed by `;` followed by space as field separator
- `-v OFS='\n'` sets newline as output field separator
- `{$1=$1}` change `$0` as per new OFS
- `1` print `$0`
- `sort -fu` sort uniquely ignoring case in alphabetic order

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, `awk` + `sort` solution, written and tested with shown samples. In case you want to use ignorecase then add `IGNORECASE=1` in `awk` code.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=" ; "
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(!a[$i]++){  print $i  }
  }
}
'  Input_file | sort
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                            ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                           ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS=" ; "                       ##Setting field separator as space semi-colon space here.
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){            ##Starting a for loop till NF here for each line.
    if(!a[$i]++){  print $i  }   ##Checking condition if current field is NOT present in array a then printing that field value here.
  }
}
'  Input_file | sort             ##Mentioning Input_file name here and passing it to sort as Input to sort the data.
```